# CustomJs callbacks not updating data source for plot

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm trying to update the data source of plot 2 based on the hovered overvalues of plot 1, so that an accompanying viz is created in plot 2 based on the data from plot 1.

Problem is I can get the data out of rect inside of the callback and format it into x and y for a line graph, but it does not update the plot only removes the placeholder values from it. 
The data object contains the x and y values that need to be displayed in p2 (the line graph) and are equal length and formatted, not sure why its not changing the sourceLine ColumnDataSource

```py
#hover tool for additional plots
p2 = figure(plot_width = 900, plot_height = 350)

#initial data source
sourceLine = ColumnDataSource(data = {'x': [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7], 'y': [6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5]})

#line to be updated
ln = p2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', line_width = 2, source = sourceLine.data)

#callback
callback = CustomJS(args={'rect': rc.data_source.data, 'line': ln.data_source}, code="""

var rdataYear = rect.YEAR;
var rdataAgeGroup = rect.AGE_GROUP;
var rdataDeaths = rect.DEATHS;

var data = {'x': [], 'y': []};
var deaths = [];
var years = [1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017
]

var indices = cb_data.index['1d'].indices;


var newarr = rect.AGE_GROUP.map((e,i) => e === rdataAgeGroup[indices] ? i : undefined).filter(x => x);

for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++){
        var index = newarr[i];
        deaths.push(rdataDeaths[index])
}

//data that needs to be inside p2 line
data['x'].push(years)
data['y'].push(deaths)

line.data = data;
line.change.emit();
""")

#hover tool with the callback 
p1.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Year', '@YEAR'), ('Age Group', '@AGE_GROUP'),('Deaths', '@DEATHS'),('Rate', '@RATE')], callback=callback))
```

I want to have the output from the callback (data) update x and y of p2.line, im kinda new to python and bokeh is a bit funky so I would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
ln = p2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', line_width = 2, source = sourceLine.data)
```

The value of `source` should be the `ColumnDataSource` itself:

```
ln = p2.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', line_width = 2, source = sourceLine)
```

When you pass a dict like `.data`, Bokeh will create an internal CDS for you automatically, as a convenience, but now this new CDS that the glyph uses has nothing to do with the one you update in the callback.

Also, don't use the `['1d']` syntax for selection indices. It has has been deprecated now for a very long time, and will guaranteed be removed for good entirely before the end of this year. Instead:

```
var indices = cb_data.index.indices
```

Additionally, your JS is not actually updating the data source correctly. The operation at the end `data['y'].push(deaths)` actually makes the list of deaths a *sublist* of the existing empty list, which is not the correct format. Here is an updated version of the JS code:

```
const rdataYear = rect.YEAR
const rdataAgeGroup = rect.AGE_GROUP
const rdataDeaths = rect.DEATHS
const years = [1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]

const indices = cb_data.index.indices;
const newarr = rect.AGE_GROUP.map((e,i) => e === rdataAgeGroup[indices] ? i : undefined).filter(x => x);

const deaths = []
for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++){
    deaths.push(rdataDeaths[newarr[i]])
}

line.data = {x: years, y: deaths}
```

Note if you actually assign to `.data` then Bokeh can detect that automatically, no need for an explicit signal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, i swapped the line over and it still doesn't work, i have a feeling that the JS part isnt updating the line, i've attached the full program if you would like to take a look https://www.codepile.net/pile/bz967Bjk plus additional files for data https://file.io/w21vFL

Comment: Data file link is a 404

Comment: must've timed out, sorry here is a working link  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18g_S6TsGr9KNYAd_gCXvUw-M-g7j9_SX/view?usp=sharing